# How to override the help a function in matlab?

Tags: matlab, documentation, overriding

I have noticed that when a function is overridden the `help fcn` is not. I created a custom function using the same name as a built in function. Trying:

```
which fcn
```

Yields the `right\function.m`, but when I use the `help` function

```
help fcn
```

I get the help for the built in function. However, if I instead type

```
help fcn.m
```

I get the correct help. This is ambiguous and disturbing and may lead to confusion about which file is the used one. That is why I wonder: **is it possible to override the help as well?**.

I know that many does not recommend overriding in matlab, but there are times when it may be worth. For this occation it means that I does not need to change all legacy code where the function is used and also it is not good to have too many version of a function (`mycdfplot` is already taken and some may have local versions as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **NO**.
*<sub>(sorry)</sub>*

To develop a bit:
If you overload your own function, you can force the help to point to a specific function by playing with the function precedence order and the order of the path. But for Matlab built-in function, they always take precedence over your custom functions.

The only way for the help to reach your custom function is how you described, by specifying `.m`

---

From Matlab *(2013b)* help:

> Note:  When multiple programs have the same name, the help command
>   determines which help text to display by applying the rules described
>   in [*Function Precedence
>   Order*](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html).
>   However, if a program has the same name as a MathWorks function, the
>   Help on Selection option in context menus always displays
>   documentation for the MathWorks function.

Comment: This seems kind of awkward doesn't it? I doubt that this behavior is necessary for the help to work as it should. I guess that matlab did this with the best intentions but this seems to have struck wrong. The reason I did this is that most statistic toolbox licenses are occupied much of the time and since `cdfplot` lacks style arguments such as `r.` and so on. I mean how hard is it to do a cdf on my own. Anyway, good answer and thanks! +1